# Status still “Pending decision” but date has changed

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review, journals, paper-submission

I submitted a paper to a Taylor & Francis journal. It was peer reviewed and the status has been “Pending decision” since January 30. On January 31, the status stayed the same but the date had changed. What does this most likely mean?

I read online it might mean that the handling editor has made a recommendation for the outcome of the manuscript which needs to be approved by the Editor in Chief (EIC). In this case, would that mean I’ll most likely get an accept or reject and not a Major revisions? I assume if it required major revisions then that probably wouldn’t need to be approved by the EIC.

Comment: It probably means that the date has changed and nothing more. Probably a duplicate of the canonical: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/75368

Comment: It probably means that some human has interacted with the journal's record for your manuscript. This could be a meaningful event (i.e. some step in the decision-making chain) but it could also be some administrative task (e.g. recording some additional correspondence sent by a reviewer, or changing the date by which the editor is supposed to make a decision. I do not think you can treat it as informative about the outcome. In any case, none of us can give you an answer beyond speculation.

Comment: Your mental energies are far better spent on something useful, not trying to read tea leaves. I'd suggest not checking 'progress' daily.